# Add Phonegap Plugin to Xcode - ERROR: Plugin 'PayPalPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying without success to implement the new Paypal Plugin (https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin) into Xcode for a HTML5 Phonegap project - Ive followed all instructions and after a few library tweaks i've now got a clean build - but when I trigger the plugin I get the following errors -

```
ERROR: Plugin 'PayPalPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. 
Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-09-13 12:02:55.092 testing[2992:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] 
[Line 116] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"PayPalPlugin258195476",
"PayPalPlugin",
"preconnect",
[
"Sandbox"
]
]
```

This is then repeated below with a slightly different error -

```
2013-09-13 12:02:56.654 testing[2992:907] ERROR: Plugin 'PayPalPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

I have added the paypalplugin.m and .h files into the plugins folder and below is a copy of my config.xml file - I'm not sure what i can do to fix the issue - do i need to add the plugin via the command line (shown here - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)?

Can anyone offer any suggestions please?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `PayPalPLugin.m` file is added to your project / target members? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19714472/885397

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration and swearing at the computer I found the answer by adding a random Phonegap plugin via the command line and looking at how it entered the plugin in my config.xml file, played around with it for a while and it eventually worked!

it was as follows -

```
<feature name="PayPalPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PayPalPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: hi Snarechops - its the latest version - 2.9