# Cordova & Ionic on ios - Device plugin not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

The problem is that `device` is not ready never under *ios emulator*.

Cordova's **Device** plugin initializes properly the object `device`, but `device.ready` is always *false*, plus all fields being **null**. That means that the plugin is not being initialized, and also `deviceready` event does not fire, and also does not work using the `$ionicPlatform.ready(...)` method (Properly imported, with `['ionic']` dependency and injected into the controller using `["$ionicPlatform", function($ionicPlatform)]`).

So far, I have tried rebuilding several times, adding the plugin several times, `ionic prepare` and more things, but nothing works.

In the *XCode's* output I get the following error:

> 2016-09-27 11:55:15.738 MyApp[74125:12496643] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Chech your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2016-09-27 11:55:15.738 MyApp[74125:12496643] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Device330720986", "Device", "getDeviceInfo", []]
>
> 2016-09-27 11:55:15.738 MyApp[74125:12496643] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Chech your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2016-09-27 11:55:15.738 MyApp[74125:12496643] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar330720987", "StatusBar", "_ready", []]

I suspect that this last `_ready` has something to do with the `deviceready` not being triggered.

## Android/Ripple

Under Android has been tested and works pretty well. Also under Ripple gives a good response.

So, what do you think that could be the problem? I have been wandering arround stack overflow and other places on the internet and I haven't seen any result trying common solutions.

Feel free to ask me for more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this once ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28075041/498949)) - It wasn't pretty but I resolved it by doing:

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

and then (you guessed it)...

```
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Yeah, somehow it works, also have issued `ionic hooks add ios` plus not doing `sudo chmod -R 777 *`, so now works!